# Python global hotkey hook module for Linux?

Tags: python, linux, keyboard, hotkeys

There seems to be plenty of python modules for windows only that work as simply as this

```
hot.addHotkey(['Ctrl', 'Alt', '7'], func)
```

Why is everything for Linux such a mess? I don't want to compile a million things, I don't want to write 100 lines of event loop code. How can I do something like the code shown above, for Linux.